# "bash: unset: `/home/USERNAME/anaconda3/envs/ENVIRONMENT': not a valid identifier" when calling conda update or deactivate

Tags: linux, bash, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

I'm on an Ubuntu system and I was following [these instructions](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#saving-environment-variables) to try and set my PYTHONHASHSEED as an environment variable in an Anaconda environment, but I must have done something wrong because now any time I run conda deactivate or conda update (with any parameters) is the said environment "bash: unset: `/home/USERNAME/anaconda3/envs/ENVIRONMENT" is printed at the end of the output. While these commands both still seem to work as desired, at the very least I'm concerned that I messed something up, and I'd like to understand what that is and how I can fix it.

In trying to fix it, I've gone back and undone the instructions I was following by deleting the files and directories the instructions had me create, but this did not fix it. Also note that this only happens with the one Anaconda environment in question, not with any others.

It seems to me that I must have (incorrectly) edited some bash script and then forgotten about it, but after quite a bit of searching I haven't been able to figure out what I did or how to fix it.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Search your scripts for the `unset` command, to see where it's run. In the instructions you linked, it's in `./etc/conda/deactivate.d/env_vars.sh`. Check to make sure they're entered correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I had already deleted the etc directory, so it's not in there. grep -r "unset" on the environment directory doesn't return anything that stands out to me (although it returns too much to look at each line carefully), while grep -r "unset /home/USERNAME/anaconda3/envs/ENVIRONMENT" (or slight variations of this) return nothing. Do you have any recommendations on how I could search for the correct script? I'm definitely a novice at all of this stuff, so it's definitely possible I'm overlooking something very simple. Thanks again!

Comment: Look for something like `unset $VARIABLENAME` (the `$` will cause trouble). You could also run `set -x` (which makes the shell print commands as it executes them) before trying to deactivate, and see what it's doing just before the error.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. I eventually just exported my environment to a yml file, deleted the environment, and then created a new environment using the yml file, which in retrospect would have saved me hours if I just started with that, but I learned a lot, especially playing around with the set -x command, and I really appreciate the help!